# Understanding Web Profilers

Tags: css, operating-system, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Developer Tools Profiling, I profiled both Javascript and CSS.

For JS, it shows Javascript `functions` and `Total %`. For CSS, it shows `Selector` and `Total %`.

If I understand correctly, the operating system gives some chunk of CPU to the browser.

Then, the Developer Tools Profiling tool gives the % of CPU that each function and/or selector uses.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Total %` is the percentage of the total profile time that a particular entry has contributed. This may or may not be equal to the total *profiling* time (i.e., the time between clicks of the `Start/Stop` button.) Profile time only counts the time that the profiled code was executed.

Example: your CSS profiling time is 1s (you clicked `Start`, waited for 1s, and clicked `Stop`). Your CSS profile time is 200ms (that is, it took your browser only 200ms to match and apply all selectors to the right DOM elements). The `*` selector's `Total %` is 12% (that is, handling the `*` selector took your browser 24ms).

You can click the `%` button in the status bar at the bottom to see the absolute times instead of percentages.